# When should I use a gerund and when an infinitive with 'like' or 'love'?

Tags: gerunds, licensing, infinitive-clauses

Do you like to cook?

Do you like cooking?

Do you love cooking?

Do you love to cook?

In which one we should use gerund?

Comment: They're all good. Others might argue a slight difference in meaning, but for all practical purpose these sentences would be understood the same, with the gerund or the infinitive. There are lots of cases in English where there are two or more ways to say the same thing, without one being "better" than the other.

Answer (score 2):

These are all correct, and you could use "Do you like to cook?" and "Do you like cooking?" to mean pretty much the same thing.

Or there could be some subtle distinction:

1) "You like to cook" could mean that you enjoy the physical act of cooking, actually being in the kitchen preparing food.

2) "You like cooking" could mean that you enjoy the broader *subject* of cooking, perhaps watching cooking shows, or reading about cooking, even if you don't actually get into the kitchen and prepare food yourself very much.